# LINQ and a natural sort order

Tags: c#, linq, natural-sort

What's the easiest way to get a LINQ query (from an SQL database - does that matter?) to order strings naturally?

For example, I'm currently getting these results:

- Project 1
- Project 10
- Project 2

What I'd like is to see is this:

- Project 1
- Project 2
- Project 10

The query I'm using is this:

```
return from p in dataContext.Projects
    orderby p.Name
    select p;
```

Comment: "Naturally" is subjective. Can you describe what you mean more specifically?

Comment: @StingyJack - In a human sort order, not a computer sort order.

Comment: HA - "Human" sort order. You mean latin dictionary order, case insensitive?  Do you have an ID for these projects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this using the .NET framework but I would suggest that you read [Natural Sorting in C#](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting) for a discussion on the topic and an open-source implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only a few years late to the party, but I was just trying to solve a similar problem and this worked for me. Hope someone else finds this helpful.

Say you have your strings in a List, try something like this:

```
List<string> projects = new List<string>
{
    "Project 1",
    "Project 10",
    "Project 2"
};
//Sort by a substring of the string value which omits the non-numeric characters
IEnumerable<string> sorted = projects.OrderBy(p => p.Substring(p.IndexOf(' ') + 2, p.Length - (p.IndexOf(' ') + 2)));
```

Comment: This is pretty good, I could also take advantage of a known pattern up front. Note that substring has a method that takes start only, and goes to the end `p => p.Substring(p.IndexOf(" ") + 1))`   (and it's a double-quote, and +1 instead of +2)